# ¿Cómo pegar texto sin formato en un Entry Xamarin forms?

Tags: formularios, xamarin

Cuando copio texto (canciones y acordes) de algun sitio web como lacuerda o similares, al pegarlo en un editor view de xamarin forms, el texto se distorsiona, los acordes aparecen en la misma linea que la letra.
He implementado un boton que extrae el texto del portapapeles en lugar de mantener presionado el editor para luego poner pegar, y funciona mejor, pero aún así hay dispositivos en los que ambas maneras de pegar el texto en el editor presentan este problema.

```
if (Clipboard.HasText)
{
   var textFromWeb = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
   txtSongEntry.Text = textFromWeb;
}
```

En algunos de estos dispositivos he visto una funcion que dice "Pegar como texto sin formato" y esa funciona de maravilla pero no todos los celulares la  tienen.
Existe alguna manera de implementar un Editor View que elimine el formato del texto que se le pega?
En mi desesperacion he intentado cosas como cambiar el "Encode" del texto antes de hacer el set en el Editor, pero no funciona.

```
public string Convert(string str)
{
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
    return str;
}
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Deberias agregar el codigo que hiciste, para que la ayuda sea en base a tu codigo

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicacion, pero como mencioné, no funciona del todo